# Error in starting julia

Tags: julia, juno-ide

I downloaded Julia(v0.5.2) from [here](https://julialang.org), then unpacked the downloaded folder. after that i install AtOM and set uber-juno for it.

when i wrote in console `2+2`, i got such error:

> We tried to launch Julia from:
>
> julia
>
> This path can be changed in the settings.
>
> Details:
>     /bin/sh: 1: julia: not found

How can i solve this problem?

thank you.

Note that: when i wrote in shell: julia myprogram.jl , 
i got such error:

> The program 'julia' is currently not installed.

while i unpacked julia.tgz by `tar`

Comment: did you add the path to Julia?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas how can i do this?

Comment: an easy way to find the Julia path is to run `which julia` from a terminal shell

Comment: http://docs.junolab.org/latest/man/installation.html#Juno-could-not-be-started.-1

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas thanks but i couldn't find "julia path" in setting.

Comment: you could also set it in  `julia-client`'s settings

Comment: @Gnimuc thanks the error solved.